# Get the runtime dimensions of an interface builder UIView

Tags: xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

When I set my UIView in an interface builder to be equal widths to the super view it sets it at 600.

When I launch my app and print out the width of the UIView it says 600.

The screen width is only 320.

How can I get the UIView to be the width of the screen instead?

Thanks

Comment: Print out in viewDidAppear, use size class and constraint to set the width to its superview's width.

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I was calling it in the viewDidLoad but I guess it hasnt been added to the hierarchy and hence not sized correctly. Thank you!